# Addition of extra " while using .Replace method in C#

Tags: c#

My problem  is when i try to add a url to a link, an extra `"` is always appended at the end of the string.

Current faulty code :

`Label add_url = "<a href=\"/test/\">link</a>";` // produces link pointing to /test/

`Label rep_url = add_url.Replace("\"/", "http://mysite.com/");` // produces a faulty link which points to http://mysite.com/test/" <- NOTE! EXTRA " HERE

Am i missing something? please help.

Comment: You need to post the rest of your code.  What you've posted can't be used to reproduce the problem.

Comment: What is `Label`? As best I can tell, `System.Web.UI.WebControls.Label` [does not have a `Replace` method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.label_methods(v=vs.110).aspx).

Comment: I take Label is a fancy name for string (using Label = System.String;)?

Comment: Adding my comment at right place now. Thanks Theraot for pointing out. Its tagged with C#, so assuming its asp.net. Not sure, if it's really necessary to have the HTML code in the codebehind. Is it possible to move the anchor tags to aspx/ascx as server side tags and set the href in the codebehind?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You probably missed the open quote, since you are replacing it:

```
Label rep_url = add_url.Replace("\"/", "\"http://mysite.com/");
```

Answer (score 1):

The trailing quote is fine, it should be there. It's the one after the equal sign that is missing.

The imbalance of quotes happens because you are removing the initial quote, not because you are inserting a trailing one:

```
Label rep_url = add_url.Replace("\"/", "\"http://mysite.com/");
```

Answer (score 0):

Please try this

```
Label rep_url = add_url.Replace("\"","\"http://mysite.com/");
```